# Power of an electrical equipment

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

Let's say I have equipment of resistance $R$ (maybe a bulb or heater). If I apply a voltage $V$ to it, the power used by the equipment will be $V^2/R$ assuming Ohm's law holds for the equipment.
If I change the voltage, the power used by the equipment changes.

But now, I have equipment with a power rating that says $P$. Now; if I apply voltage $V$ to the equipment, I get a current $I$ given by $I = P/V$. But now, if I change the voltage, the power won't change; instead, the current will change.

Why is this so? So how is the power across the equipment constant in the second case? Is there something else that I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power rating only applies at a specific voltage, e.g. 110V or 240V. If you change the voltage, the equipment will consume more or less power, as determined by its resistance.

If the equipment uses $P$ power at $V$ voltage, then it uses a current of $I=P/V$. Its resistance is thus $R=V/I$.

If we now change the voltage to $V_1$, the resistance R (which does not change) means a new current $I_1=V_1/R$ flows, and the new power is $P=V_1I_1$.

Comment: Ahh, Got it! So, the power rating is given for a *specific voltage*, and changing voltage changes the power consumed. Thanks.

Comment: Just remember that, with most equipment, changing the voltage is not a good idea. Increasing the voltage (say, plugging 110V equipment into a 220V socket) may be destructive. Lowering the voltage may cause erratic or faulty behaviour. That said, a lot of low-power equipment like plug-packs will happily work from 100 to 240V.

Comment: > Increasing the voltage (say, plugging 110V equipment into a 220V socket) may be destructive   I'd like to add that *decreasing* the voltage may also be destructive, as in putting a 6 volt battery in a 12 volt car and trying to engage the starter motor. Since the 6 volts will spin the motor very slowly (if at all) the motor (which, while spinning, acts as a generator) doesn't produce enough back-voltage to limit the current, essentially a dead short.